# What is the standard way for writing default values in a python docstring?

Tags: python, numpy, docstring

I have a function with parameters set to default values.  I'm using a [NumPy-style](https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format.html#docstring-standard) docstring, but I've seen the default values written elsewhere.  What is the commonly accepted placement for writing "default" in the docstring?

```
def some_func(a_num=None, a_string=None):
    ''' A function that does something special.

    Parameters
    ==========
    a_num : int, default 100                        # is it written here?
        An important number.
    a_string : str, default 'foo'
        A useful string.  Default is 'foo'.         # or here?    
 
    '''
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you read further in the document you linked it looks like there's no one standard style:

> Optional keyword parameters have default values, which are displayed as part of the function signature. They can also be detailed in the description:
>
> ```
> Description of parameter `x` (the default is -1, which implies summation
> over all axes).
> ```
>
> When a parameter can only assume one of a fixed set of values, those values can be listed in braces, with the default appearing first:
>
> ```
> order : {'C', 'F', 'A'}
>     Description of `order`.
> ```

I would recommending picking a style for your own project and sticking to it.